# In a photography context, what is the opposite of a keeper?

Tags: single-word-requests, photography

If I take a sequence of photos and decide that one of them is the best of the bunch, I might call it a keeper. What would the others be called? I'm looking for something slightly less harsh and judgemental than "reject".

Comment: I'm not sure why "reject" has such a negative stigma – especially in this context. I like [this dictionary definition](http://www.wordnik.com/words/reject): _a thing that is .. set aside as inferior in quality_. But if that rings too judgmental, there's always _non-keeper._

Comment: "For the files"?  "Wallpaper"?  "To give to Grandma?" "Runners-up"?

Comment: You can always just refer to them as *the others* or *the rest*.  I took about 100 pictures;  here's my 5 keepers and here's the rest of them.

Comment: How about "swipe left"?  Or, if you must, "non-selected".

Comment: a **tosser**..... ;)

Comment: I've always used *junker* for the opposite of *keeper* when it comes to snapshots.

Comment: All the photographers I know (myself included) use _reject_ when dealing with demoted shots in a stack. There’s nothing harsh or judgmental about it. (Note: the photo in the stack that you decide to keep is not usually called a _keeper_, but the _pick_.)

Answer (score 1):

Discard.

Alternates.

Didn't make the cut.

Runner-ups.

Comment: Are you and oldbag gonna debate "Runner-ups" vs. "Runners-up"?

Comment: I'll win by tenacity alone.

Answer (score 0):

As you edit your selection, you can pick the strongest image and leave out the "less compelling" and "redundant" images.

Answer (score -1):

> "reject" doesn't have such a negative stigma — especially in this context —, however you could consider this dictionary definition(†): *a thing that is set aside as inferior in quality*.
>
> If that rings too judgmental, there's always *non-keeper*, though.
>
> —J.R.

(†) http://www.wordnik.com/words/reject

Answer (score -1):

You could euphemistically indicate they are the photos that you have not picked out to be rated or ranked. In this vein, you might call them ***unsorted photos*** (not sorted), or ***assorted photos*** (a random collection).

Comment: @jl6: If the word I suggested missed the intention of your question, please say so, and I will delete the answer. Thanks.